# JavaScript ReferenceError: member is not defined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, member

So I'm trying to code a utility bot on my server and for some reason, this error popped out "Reference error"

ReferenceError: member is not defined

Every single time I solve a problem another one pops out. I know you guys will be asking me to save it (member) but I already did, like 7 times?

This is my current code:

```js
const { Discord } = require("discord.js");

exports.run = async(client, msg, args) => {
    if(!msg.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) return msg.reply('You do not have permission to use this command!')

    var user = msg.mentions.user.first() || msg.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
    if(!user) return msg.reply('You did not mention a user for me to punish!')
    var member;
    try {
        member = await msg.guild.members.fetch(user)
    } catch(err) {
        member = null;
    }
    if(member){
        if(member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return msg.reply('You cannot ban a fellow staff member!');
    }

    var reason = args.splice(1).join(' ');
    if(!reason) return msg.reply('Please make sure to specify a reason for me to punish this user!')
    var channel = msg.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === 'mod-logs');
    var verify = msg.guild.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === 'white_check_mark')
    var log = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('0xecd776')
    .setDescription(`${verify} ${user} has been kicked by ${msg.author} for "**${reason}**"`)
    channel.send(logs);

    var userLog = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('0xecd776')
    .setDescription(`You have been banned from the server! Thats sadge. You can appeal the ban by message a staff member!`)
    try {
        await user.send(userLog);
    } catch(err) {
        console.warn(err);
    }
    

msg.guild.members.ban(user);
var confir = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor('0xecd776')
.setDescription(`${verify} ${user} has been banned by ${msg.author} for "**${reason}**"`)
msg.channel.send(confir);
msg.delete();

}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    const { Discord } = require("discord.js");

    exports.run = async(client, msg, args) => {
        if(!msg.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) return msg.reply('You do not have permission to use this command!')

        var user = msg.mentions.user.first() || msg.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
        if(!user) return msg.reply('You did not mention a user for me to punish!')
        var member;
        try {
            member = await msg.guild.members.fetch(user)
        } catch(err) {
            member = null;
        }
        if(member){
            if(member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return msg.reply('You cannot ban a fellow staff member!');
        }

        var reason = args.splice(1).join(' ');
        if(!reason) return msg.reply('Please make sure to specify a reason for me to punish this user!')
        var channel = msg.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === 'mod-logs');
        var verify = msg.guild.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === 'white_check_mark')
        var log = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('0xecd776')
        .setDescription(`${verify} ${user} has been kicked by ${msg.author} for "**${reason}**"`)
        channel.send(logs);

        var userLog = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('0xecd776')
        .setDescription(`You have been banned from the server! Thats sadge. You can appeal the ban by message a staff member!`)
        try {
            await user.send(userLog);
        } catch(err) {
            console.warn(err);
        }
        

    msg.guild.members.ban(user);
    var confir = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('0xecd776')
    .setDescription(`${verify} ${user} has been banned by ${msg.author} for "**${reason}**"`)
    msg.channel.send(confir);
    msg.delete();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```js
const CUser = message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || message.guild.member(message.author);
        let member
    if (message.mentions.members.first()) {
    member = CUser
    } else {
    member = CUser.user
    }
```

instead of your:

```js
    var user = msg.mentions.user.first() || msg.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
    if(!user) return msg.reply('You did not mention a user for me to punish!')
    var member;
    try {
        member = await msg.guild.members.fetch(user)
    } catch(err) {
        member = null;
    }
```

#### Please note this code was written on discord.js version 12.5.3

Comment: thanks for the help but now it says SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules, even thou my function is async